# $this->db->last_query() returns NULL in Codeigniter 4. How to get query SQL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-4

I just started learning Codeigniter 4. My query always generates NULL and I don't know why. How can I see the generated SQL Select command just like Codeigniter 3?

In Codeigniter 3 this command does the job:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

And this is my controller code in Codeigniter 4 that I need to get the generated query:

```
$cityModel = new CityModel();
$cities = $cityModel
    ->select('city.name AS cityName')
    ->select('county.name AS countryName')
    ->select('province.name AS provinceName')
    ->join('province', 'city.province_id = province.id', 'left')
    ->join('county', 'city.county_id = county.id', 'left')
    ->result();
```

**Update:**
I tried this code but it's returning an empty string:

```
var_export((string)$cityModel->db->getLastQuery());
```

Comment: *"My query always generates NULL"*? maybe `county.name` should be `country.name`. *"What's the $db? It's not defined in the controller"*? you could define it like this: `$db=$this->db;`

Comment: `echo  $this->db->getLastQuery();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getCompiledSelect it will return the query SELECT command.

```
$sql = $cityModel->getCompiledSelect();
echo $sql;
```

Comment: in your case it will be $cityModel->getCompiledSelect(); it attaches with $this->db->getCompiledSelect()

Comment: Not work for a join query?

Answer (score 12):

This should display the final query:

```
$cityModel->getLastQuery()->getQuery()
```

Answer (score 5):

In CI 4 Refer [Doc](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/queries.html)

you can use `getLastQuery()` as

```
$query = $db->getLastQuery();
echo (string)$query;
```

Comment: What's the $db? It's not defined in the controller.

Comment: use `$this->db` to get the last query.

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you to get the last query in codeigniter 4.

```
 $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
 $data = $builder->get()->getResult();
 echo $this->db->getLastQuery(); die;
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$myModel = new MyModel();// your any model
    
$myModel->db->getLastQuery()->getQuery();
```

`$this->db` is not directly accessible from controller, but if you have any `Model` instance then you can have the full access to `db` object.

Comment: What's the difference between this approach and Piyush's answer from September? Doesn't `$this` translate to `$myModel` in this case?

Comment: In My Case, `$this->db` was not accessible from Controller, I need to create instance for it.
But I tried with my Model instance and it worked.

Comment: That's useful to know. I'd recommend [edit]ing your answer to include that information so that it's clear upfront how it differs from Piyush's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will work in CI 4

```
$this->db->getLastQuery()->getQuery();
```

Comment: Worked for me, it returning the query.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your class

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$query = $db->getLastQuery();
echo $query;
```

Comment: Won't this make a new connection, which doesn't yet have a "last query"?

Answer (score -1):

Simply just use `$this->db->getLastQuery();`