# How to implement this kind of concept in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

In codeigniter 4 there is a Db helper or query builder when i `print_r($db->getLastQuery())` it returns whole methods and other information or when `echo $db->getLastQuery()` it returns last query.
How the same function returns diffrent output at same time ??

Comment: Relevant: [What's the equivalent of $this->db->last_query() in Codeigniter 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60000501/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `getLastQuery` returns object which implements magic method [__toString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), and with `echo` variable is casted to string, while `print_r` just prints raw object.

Comment: This is correct. The return of `getLastQuery` is in fact an instance of `CodeIgniter\Database\Query`; this `Query` class has a `toString` method that is implicitly called when PHP attempts to convert `echo`'s argument from an Object to a String.