# CodeIgniter4: How to get executed MySQL queries between sending an HTTP request and receiving an HTTP response

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-4

1. Start.
2. HTTP request.
3. Execute SQL queries.
4. HTTP response.

I want to get queries between requests and responses (how many queries and the raw SQL query).

`->getLastQuery()` only returns 1 last query.  I want to save all queries between sending an HTTP request and receiving an HTTP response.

##### My failed example;

```php
<?php

class Logger implements FilterInterface
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {

    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $this->db->getLastQuery()->getOriginalQuery();
        if ($this->db->getLastQuery()->isWriteType()) {
            echo "updated or write query";
        }
        $return = $this->db->getLastQuery()->getOriginalQuery();
        $logger = new Client();
        $logger->logQueries($return);
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [What's the equivalent of $this->db->last_query() in Codeigniter 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60000501/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

Try using [The Debug Toolbar](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/testing/debugging.html#the-debug-toolbar). *The Debug Toolbar provides at-a-glance information about the current page request, including benchmark results, queries you have run, request and response data, and more.*

---

Alternatively, you could tap into the execution of your application by subscribing to the `DBQuery` event. This can be done by registering with the `app/Config/Events.php` class to let it know that you want to perform an action when that event is triggered.

[Defining an Event](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/extending/events.html#defining-an-event)

> Most events are defined within the `app/Config/Events.php` file. You
> can subscribe an action to an event with the `Events` class’ `on()`
> method. The first parameter is the name of the event to subscribe to.
> The second parameter is a callable that will be run when that event is
> triggered:

> ```php
> <?php
>
> use CodeIgniter\Events\Events;
>
> Events::on('pre_system', ['MyClass', 'myFunction']);
> ```
>
> In this example, whenever the pre_system event is executed, an
> instance of `MyClass` is created and the `myFunction()` method is run.
> Note that the second parameter can be any form of
> [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)
> that PHP recognizes:
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> // Call a standalone function
> Events::on('pre_system', 'some_function');
>
> // Call on an instance method
> $user = new User();
> Events::on('pre_system', [$user, 'someMethod']);
>
> // Call on a static method
> Events::on('pre_system', 'SomeClass::someMethod');
>
> // Use a Closure
> Events::on('pre_system', static function (...$params) {
>     // ...
> });
> ```

#### Solution

In your `app/Config/Events.php` class, subscribe to the `DBQuery` event.

*`DBQuery` -: Called after a database query whether successful or not. Receives the `\CodeIgniter\Database\Query` object.* - [Event Points](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/extending/events.html#event-points)

```php
Events::on("DBQuery", static function (\CodeIgniter\Database\Query $query) {

    // Add your SQL query logging logic here. I.e:
    log_message("error", $query->getQuery());

});
```

Comment: I tried and it worked. So does it lose performance?